# Why is there code that is executed when the thread is blocked using coroutines?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Why does it print 'a' after 1 second if the thread is blocked for 3 seconds?

When a thread is blocked it can't do any computation until it is unlocked. How come is it possible to execute println('a') while this thread is blocked by Thread.sleep()?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        delay(1000L)
        println("a")
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000L)
}
```

Comment: Dispatchers.Default has max limit of threads same as core count of your CPU, for example if you have 4 cores, it could spawn upto 4 threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Dispatcher schedules coroutines to its own thread pool, so in your example `delay(1000L)` and `Thread.sleep(3000L)` are executed in separate threads.